# how to dynamically set the number of states in angular

Tags: angular, angular-animations

```
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  animations: [
    trigger('slide', [
      state('1', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
      state('2', style({ transform: 'translateX(-50%)' })),
      transition('* => *', animate(300))
    ])
  ]
})

export class SlidePanelComponent {
  @Input() numberOfStatesToHave

... more code
```

How can I dynamically set the number of states in angular using the @input decorator?

For example if the @Input numberOfStatesToHave is 3, how can I have three animations states in the animations 'array' in the @Component decorator? And also dynamically pass values to the transform css property?

Comment: In that case you need to use the Animationbuilder. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationBuilder&ved=2ahUKEwjR5-Oi_aDlAhXgIbcAHYcrBIQQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1uB7gk6xBAoRBhuBOROesN

Comment: @SplitterAlex Thanks for pointing me there. But I do not understand some of what is happening there, like `player.play();` where does `play` come from?
`

Comment: @SplitterAlex I got it! : https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationPlayer#play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing research(thanks to @SplitterAlex comment that pointed me to the right direction), I have come up with a solution.

To dynamically create animation states you should have the animations logic inside the @Components decorator but rather you should use angular's [Animationbuilder](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationBuilder).

This [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-builder) helped me understand how the animation builder works as it contrasts it with doing the animation inside the @Component decorator.

[Here is my complete code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-builder-xw21eg?file=app%2Fslide-panel%2Fslide-panel.component.ts) of dynamically setting the number of animation states in angular.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. But my suggestion for your requirements is below.

```
const numberOfStatesToHave = localStorage.getItem('NUMBEROFSTATESTOHAVE')

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    animations: [
      trigger('slide', numberOfStatesToHave)
    ]
})
```

If before call this component set that `localStorage` value